# Whats the significance of the $|a|=6$ and $|b|=7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The problem is as follows:

> If $a,b$ and $c$ are group elements and $|a|=6$ and $|b|=7$, express $(a^4c^{-2}b^4)^{-1}$ without negative exponents.

Do I have to rearrange the $(a^4c^{-2}b^4)^{-1}$ someway assuming the group is abelian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to assume that the group is abelian. Just note that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$. (Note the reversal.)

In your case, this implies $(a^4c^{-2}b^4)^{-1}=(b^4)^{-1}(c^{-2})^{-1}(a^4)^{-1}=b^{-4}c^2a^{-4}$. Justify the last step and use the hypotheses on the orders to convert negative exponents to positive ones.

Comment: So what is the significance in knowing the orders of a and b?

Comment: @DerekMarlon, $b^{-4} = b^{-4} 1 = b^{-4} b^7 = \cdots$.

Comment: @DerekMarlon You know that $a^6=1$. So $a^{-4}=a^{-4}\cdot 1=a^{-4}\cdot a^6=\cdots$?

Comment: $|b|=7$ means $b^7=e$, the identity.  So what can you say about $b^{-4}$?

Comment: Oh i see thank you very much